# Group 10 columns of data to gain distinct count of rows Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I'm trying to display all of the distinct values within this table (there are many other columns in this table) and show how many rows each distinct value shows in.

I have tried to use group by but this does not work. It needs to be filterable by country from another column but i can do that by page filter.

I am trying to show what the top 5 associations are in terms of appearance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MILEn.png)

Answer (score 0):

Put the 10 columns in a Table visual. Then create this measure and add it too. Then sort descending on Distinct.

```
Distinct = COUNTROWS('Your Table Name')
```

To see only the Top 5, go to the Filter pane, and pick the first column and set the Filter type to Top N, and then Top 5 by the `Distinct` measure.